# How can I use the input.app property's index.html file as my main index.html during development?

Tags: vite, rollupjs

I am trying to use a single index.html for both development and building.  My vite.config.js is structured like this:

```
export default {
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        rollupOptions: {
          input: {
            app: 'templates/index.html',
          },
          root: 'templates/'
        },
        outDir: '../server/dist',
        assetsDir: 'static',
        root: 'templates/'
      },
    root: 'templates/',
    base: './',
    server: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I have it set so that the index.html after running "npx vite build" is placed inside of a templates directory.  Unfortunately, this setup does not allow running "npm run dev" without a copy of the index.html outside of the templates directory in my tree... and therefore I have to have the following project tree to run "npm run dev":

```
-Project
---templates
------index.html
---index.html
---{other stuff}
```

This requires me to develop with the upper-level index.html, then to build the project I have to copy the upper-level index.html and replace the templates/index.html with the copy.  This is annoying and I'm wondering if there is a way to use the templates/index.html as the primary index.html such that it is used for both builds and development.

I have tried setting the **root** property in the vite.config.js file to:
root: 'templates/'
(and also tried setting root to: '/templates', '/templates/', 'templates/index.html', etc.)

This just results in an error when I run "npm run dev" which says:

> Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.